# explicitly close db connection in slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, play-slick

Here is code I am trying to optimise:

```
object UserRepo
{
  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  val dbName = "db"

  lazy val queryAllUsers = for (user <- users) yield user

  type UserRow =  (Int, String, String, String)

  def getAll() : Future[ Seq[UserRow] ] =
  {
    val db = Database.forConfig( dbName )

    val f: Future[Seq[UserRow]] = db.run( queryAllUsers.result )

    f.onComplete {
      case Success(_) => { db.close() }
      case Failure(_) => { db.close() }
    }

    f
  }

}
```

I going to have number of query to the DB I am trying to get rid of string where I am creating DB connection. Is there any execution context I can use to close connection explicitly ?? so code will look more concise ?

Is there option to get used db connection within Future.onComplete scope??

Thanks

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to create (and later close) db connection for this single operation?

Shouldn't you have connection being opened/closed on some kind of startup/shutdown of your application and resused whenever you perform query?

Comment: Good point, you mean to manage db connection on application level? Yes, this could be nice, but as I understand I will have to create this code manually? is there something build in in the slick?

Comment: Are you using `Play` ?

Comment: I've created separate project to manage all work related to database/data and planning to reuse this in Play project as also in the data processing services

Comment: If you are using play it may be useful to take a look at `play-slick` and simply use `DI`. Let me update the answer with `Play` style `DI`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for your comment ( [explicitly close db connection in slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328636/explicitly-close-db-connection-in-slick#comment71809978_42328636) ) normally what you do is to create a connection on an application startup (or lazily on first use) and then closing it at the application end.

This obviously all depends what kind of application you are running:

- if you are having `DI` container you would probably manage some of this in your `DI` mechanisms (like `Module`s in `Guice`)
- if you are having web application, specifically e.g. `Play` - you would probably use `play-slick` that does this initialization / shutting down for you (kind of).

**General way (no DI)**

The easiest general way (assuming you are not using `DI` or `play-slick`) of doing this would be perhaps something like this:

```
object DbManager {
  lazy val db = createDb

  private def createDb = {
      Database.forConfig("db")
  }

  def close {
      db.close
  }
}
```

Then your code would be:

```
object UserRepo
{
  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  lazy val queryAllUsers = for (user <- users) yield user

  type UserRow =  (Int, String, String, String)

  def getAll() : Future[ Seq[UserRow] ] =
  {
    DbManager.db.run( queryAllUsers.result )
  }   
}
```

Above code doesn't do any cleaning up - this would need to be added to some kind of hook when application is closing (in case e.g. of web application) or you would need to manually call `DbManager.close` at some specified time (when you are closing the application).

**Play slick**

You would probably need to start from here: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/basic (most basic sample showing `play-slick` configuration).

Updating your answer with this would be:

```
class UserRepo @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile])
{
  import driver.api._

  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  lazy val queryAllUsers = for (user <- users) yield user

  type UserRow =  (Int, String, String, String)

  def getAll() : Future[ Seq[UserRow] ] =
  {
    db.run( queryAllUsers.result )
  }   
}
```

In this scenario you wouldn't call:

```
UserRepo.getAll
```

but you would rather need to inject it:

```
class MyClientCode @Inject() (userRepo: UserRepo) {
  ...
  userRepo.getAll
  ...
}
```

You would need to obviously configure it in your configuration but this should be very straightforward to do with the sample provided above.

So in short your `Play` application will have database connection configuration and would do all initialization / cleaning up. Your external modules (like the one you described in your comment) would simply pull `DatabaseConfigProvider` as `Guice` managed dependency (as show above).

Comment: well, considering how concise scala code could be I am considering to use play-slick for my project: (Play project + Akk processing services). So, I will have separate project for data models/table mapping etc. Thanks,